# Why does ScrollView throw me a warning message?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, scrollview

I have a problem with React Native ScrollView, it throws me a danger message
It’s supposed to be the same as the design but I cannot visualize it

message: 
WARNING- VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollView with the same orientation Use- anorther VirtualizedLists- Backed conintainer instead

Design:
[image]

code:

```js
  <View>
                    <SearchBar
                        term={term}
                        onTermChange={setTerm}
                        onTermSubmit={() => searchApi(term)}
                    />
                    {errorMessage ? <Text>{errorMessage}</Text> : null}

                    <ScrollView>
                        <ResultList
                            title=''
                            results={results}
                        />
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
```

Comment: Maybe because ResultList uses an embedded ScrollView? So you don't need to wrap it into another one. (just saying, i don't know much of react native)

Comment: @user12979570 you ResultList component is most likely a `FlatList`

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli ResultList have FlatList so ¿have i delete  scrollView?

Comment: @MatPag np, i will try your solutions

Comment: @NicolásCabeza yes check out my answer :) ... and try to apply it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in here:

```
<ScrollView>
  <ResultList title="" results={results} />
</ScrollView>
```

If you don't have any scrollable-content inside your `ScrollView` ... then you could just remove that `ScrollView` wrapping your `<ResultList />` and you'll be good to go...

But If you do have other scollable-content -> then try to include them as `ListHeaderComponent` or `ListFooterComponent` of your `FlatList` ...